# merge two data frame if start and end date of df2 comes in range of start and end date of df1 in python (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

i have two dataframe df1 and df2

df1=

```
id      start        end
 a  1/12/2022 18/12/2022
 a 19/12/2022 25/12/2022
 a 26/12/2022 31/12/2022
 b 01/12/2022 20/12/2022
 b 21/12/2022 31/12/2022
 c 01/12/2022 31/12/2022
 d 01/12/2022 15/12/2022
 d 16/12/2022 31/12/2022
```

and second data frame as

df2

```
id    start_2      end_2  number
 a 15/12/2022 15/12/2022       1
 b 17/12/2022 19/12/2022       3
 b 25/12/2022 27/12/2022       2
 c 12/12/2022 12/12/2022       1
 d 03/12/2022 04/12/2022       2
 d 25/12/2022 25/12/2022       1
```

I want to merge both dataframe left join (df1 and df2) by id . And adjust column 'number' in same date range(start and end date) coming in df1 . Like if in df2 id 'a' has number 1 it should come in first row of 'a'(1/12/2022 to  18/12/2022) not in other slot. Other slot should be zero. Like below

Resulted df

```
id      start        end  number
 a  1/12/2022 18/12/2022       1
 a 19/12/2022 25/12/2022       0
 a 26/12/2022 31/12/2022       0
 b 01/12/2022 20/12/2022       3
 b 21/12/2022 31/12/2022       2
 c 01/12/2022 31/12/2022       1
 d 01/12/2022 15/12/2022       2
 d 16/12/2022 31/12/2022       1
```

Note if two number lies in same slot of df1,there should be groupby sum.

Comment: Can you check the first record of 'd'? Why it's not 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat and the groupby with the size() method.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df.groupby(["start", "end"]).size()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge on `id` then filter out your list:

```
# Convert to DatetimeIndex if necessary
df1['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['start'], dayfirst=True)
df1['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['end'], dayfirst=True)
df2['start_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['start_2'], dayfirst=True)
df2['end_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['end_2'], dayfirst=True)

# Merge on id, reset_index to preserve original index on merge
out = df1.reset_index().merge(df2, on='id', how='left')

# Check intervals
out['indicator'] = (out['start'] < out['start_2']) & (out['end_2'] < out['end'])

# Filter the list and set to 0 other slots
out = out.loc[out.groupby('index')['indicator'].idxmax()]
out.loc[~out['indicator'], 'number'] = 0

# Get the final dataframe
out = out[df1.columns.tolist() + ['number']].set_index(df1.index)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  id      start        end  number
0  a 2022-12-01 2022-12-18       1
1  a 2022-12-19 2022-12-25       0
2  a 2022-12-26 2022-12-31       0
3  b 2022-12-01 2022-12-20       3
4  b 2022-12-21 2022-12-31       2
5  c 2022-12-01 2022-12-31       1
6  d 2022-12-01 2022-12-15       0
7  d 2022-12-16 2022-12-31       1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around. After merging you set `start` and `end` condition then make a good use of `.loc` and `groupby`

```py
df1["start"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["start"], dayfirst=True)
df1["end"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["end"], dayfirst=True)
df2["start_2"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["start_2"], dayfirst=True)
df2["end_2"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["end_2"], dayfirst=True)


merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="id", how="left")
merged_df["number_adj"] = 0

start_condition = (merged_df["start_2"] >= merged_df["start"]) & (merged_df["start_2"] <= merged_df["end"])
end_condition = (merged_df["end_2"] >= merged_df["start"]) & (merged_df["end_2"] <= merged_df["end"])

merged_df.loc[start_condition | end_condition, "number_adj"] = merged_df["number"]
merged_df = merged_df.groupby(["id", "start", "end"]).sum().reset_index()
merged_df.drop("number", axis=1, inplace=True)
merged_df.rename(columns={"number_adj": "number"}, inplace=True)

print(merged_df)
```

Output:

```
  id      start        end  number
0  a 2022-12-01 2022-12-18       1
1  a 2022-12-19 2022-12-25       0
2  a 2022-12-26 2022-12-31       0
3  b 2022-12-01 2022-12-20       3
4  b 2022-12-21 2022-12-31       2
5  c 2022-12-01 2022-12-31       1
6  d 2022-12-01 2022-12-15       2
7  d 2022-12-16 2022-12-31       1
```